# Is it worthwhile to implement observer pattern in PHP?

Tags: php, cocoa-design-patterns

I have been meaning to make use of design pattern in PHP, such as the observer pattern, but that I have to recreate the observers' relationship each time the page is loaded pains me. As references are saved as a new concrete objects in session, there is no way to preserve relationships between subscribers and their observers unless you use a GUID or some other properties to form a lookup, and store that property instead.

With the cost of recreating the relationships each time a page is loaded, is it worthwhile to use design patterns such as observers in PHP, compared to having a clean design? Any real-world experience to share?

Comment: How are you going to implement the observer pattern in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recreation of the relationships themselves would probably take the least amount of time, since the objects are passed around as references.

Answer (score 3):

That's a somewhat odd question to ask for a programming language that - by design - shares nothing and recreates the entire environment on each request anyway.

When talking about *cost*, you have to take into account that finding and recreating the session data on each request takes up resources too. I don't know how many relations we are talking about in your app, but attaching all required subjects with observers in a bootstrap sounds like a clean and valid approach to me. You could push the responsibility for this into a manager class for increased maintainability.

If in doubt about performance, benchmark.